# SSH Tunnel (Port forwarding) in background

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, background-process, port-forwarding

I have a command to forward a port from my computer to a server, as follows:

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 myserver.com
```

I would like to run this command in background. I don't need to enter user and password since I already setup a public key.

I tried adding `&` at the end, as follows:
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 myserver.com&
But, I got the following error:

```
[1]  + 30825 suspended (tty output)
```

I tried also `nohup` , as follows:

```
nohup ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 myserver.com&
exit
```

but the port is not forwarding.

Finally, I tried `ssh -f` , as follows:

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 myserver.com
```

and, I got the following error:

```
Cannot fork into background without a command to execute.
```

My goal is to keep the ssh connection active in background without keeping the terminal open. Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mention `ssh -f`, which is correct, but you missed `-N`, which is the remaining piece of the puzzle:

> **`-N`** Do not execute a remote command. This is useful for just forwarding ports. [...]

So close! Try this

```
ssh -fN -L 8000:localhost:8888 myserver.com
```

Comment: @roaima do i need to care about a timeout or is this only for sshfs? The process works infinite till i kill /suspend/reboot the background process?

Comment: How can I stop this tunnel?

Comment: @Tobia kill the process (either explicitly with `kill` or implicitly by logging out)